# ImportError: No module named injectpkg.database

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to the Python language. I am using Python 2.6 in Windows machine and i have set the PYTHONPATH as said in the document for the No module issue.

I have set of Python files which is running fine in the client machine but throws

```
ImportError: No module named injectpkg.database
```

in my Windows machine when i try to run the file.

Where injectpkg is the custom module. But the module is there only and i didnt change anything after downloaded the set of files from the client machine. And other simple programs are working fine. So when i try to connect to the module only, it is not working.

Below is the code snippet from the file,

```
import logging
from injectpkg.database import serverdb2local
from injectpkg.decorator import hashdirfile
from injectpkg.decorator import actionpath
```

Please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Can you advise what you did to install injectpkg? Did this come with a .msi installer file or just the raw files to download?

If you just downloaded the files then navigating to the directory where they are stored and running:

```
python setup.py install
```

should install this for you.

If there is no setup.py file then you could try adding the path with the files in to your PYTHONPATH environment variable (or pasting the directory to somewhere already in your PYTHONPATH) and making sure all of the sub directories you need have a file named `__init__.py` in them (okay of this is empty).

Comment: Its just set of raw files. (No msi installer)

Comment: @Yadheendran, if you navigate to the dir where you saved the files is there a setup.py file?

Comment: Yes i see the file in the location C:\Python26\Tools\Scripts\setup.py

Comment: @Yadheendran I mean in the path where you saved the files for the injectpkg module.

Comment: No. There is no setup.py in the client directory and files. I did Windows search in that directory. :(

Comment: @Yadheendran I have updated my answer with something else you can try.